# Will reusing a UIImage in the thumbnail version of the image be faster?

Tags: performance, ios5, uiimage, uibutton

I have a huge amount of images of size 768 by 1024.
I want to make a scroll view with their thumbnailed versions as programmatically generated buttons.
Now my question is:
Should I make a thumbnail for each image and add these as a resource and create my buttons using these small (100x100 pixel) versions or should I use the same big images but just make the button of size 100x100?
Will the second one try to load the whole big image first and then resize it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to see this stack post re lazy loading of images in UIScrollView:

[UIScrollView lazy loading of images to reduce memory usage and avoid crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786614/uiscrollview-lazy-loading-of-images-to-reduce-memory-usage-and-avoid-crash)

Also see the UIScrollView sample apps and discussion. They cover this issue