# Add new image and remove old image from image view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

In my ipad app, i has 200 images and i add these images into an array.
Then add this array into image view by looping.
Then, i add this image view as sub view of scroll view.

When i open app, my app is crash.
I try with reducing image size. But, it didn't work.

One of my friend told firstly i should add only image1 and image2.
When user scroll image1, then it show image2.
After that image1 is remove from image view.
And add image3 to image view.

He told it can maintain memory usage.
But, i don't know how can i do that? :D
Please, give me some example.
Thanks in advance.

My code is here,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super loadView];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UIScrollView *ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

// Create a UIImage to hold Info.png
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-001.jpg"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-002.jpg"];
UIImage *image200 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-200.jpg"];

NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1,image2,...,image200,nil];

NSInteger numberOfViews = 200;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) 
{
CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

UIImageView *ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
[ImageView setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

[ScrollView addSubview:ImageView];
}
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:ScrollView];
```

Comment: You should probably use a table view, not a scroll view for your images. That way, you only load the images that are visible on screen, not every image. As the table scrolls, the cells are reused, and you populate them from your array, just like any other data for a table (but the array should contain the image names, not the actual images, so the images are only instantiated when you put them in the table).

Comment: For reference, you should read up on "lazy loading" - the gist is to only load assets as needed to avoid running out of memory. You may want to take a look at the code I posted in this answer about UIScrollView and lazy loading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14661487/840992

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accessing the images array at indexes 0..200, but it contains only three elements.  Either set `numberOfViews = 3;`, or index into the array like this:

```
ImageView.image = images[i%3];
```

The modulo index will cause you to add each of the three images in a repeating sequence and still let you test with a larger number of scrollView subviews.  I doubt that your crash is about memory with only 200 images, unless they are super-huge ones.

Comment: yeah, and i'll edit to add cooler property syntax, too.  :)  also @NightHunter - suggest you use lower case on stack variable names (imageView, not ImageView).

Comment: @danh, thanks for your quick reply, i don't mean only three image. There are 200 images.     UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-001.jpg"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-002.jpg"];
    UIImage *image200 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image-200.jpg"];   And  total 200 images size is 300Mb.(Each Image has around 2Mb). I reduce their size. But, didn't work. How should i do?

Comment: so you have 200 source lines creating those images, and then init the array with a list of 200+nil args?  i'll bet for sure there's a copy/paste bug in there somewhere.  please paste what the console says on the crash.

Comment: @danh, i want to show all of my code. But, comment has characters limit. When i run my app, i don't see any images and i can only see grey screen on my view. I think my coding take a lot of memory. I want to make add new image and remove old image. How can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table view to display your images. You don't want to create an array of all those images, because that puts all those images into memory -- not a good thing. You don't even need to create an array to hold the names, since they have names you can easily construct from an integer (which you can get from indexPath.row in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method). Something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 200;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image-%.3d.jpg",indexPath.row +1];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    cell.imageView.image = image;
    return cell;
}
```

This example just uses the cell's default imageView to show the images, which is pretty small. You would probably want to create a custom cell with a larger image view in it (or a couple side by side if you want more than one image per row).

Comment: thanks for your help. I really want to use table view. But, my app is almost finish about 90%. Just only has such kind of error. I didn't think about memory management for my app. I thought it doesn't meter for me. But, now i'm in trouble. I don't want to make it again from beginning. Pls, give me some advice how can i recode my code. Thanks again.

Comment: @NightHunter, I don't know if this will help (Depends on memory issues), but get rid of those 200 lines where you create the images and get rid of the array also. When you call setImage in your loop, use the code I have above (imageName =... and image = ...) to populate your image views (you would use i instead of indexPath.row when you create imageName).