# How to add images dynamically inside UIScrollView in iPhone

Tags: ios, sdk, uiscrollview, uiimage

In my iPhone app i am getting around 300 images url from web server, i need to display all the images on UIScrollView in 3x3 row and column format. Once i get all the url from web server, convert them into UIImage and display image. Everything works fine, however after loading 200 images app crashes, I have read a lot its some thing memory kind of issue with UIScrollView, so how can we work on this. I have read apple documentation also, however its not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView lazy loading of images to reduce memory usage and avoid crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786614/uiscrollview-lazy-loading-of-images-to-reduce-memory-usage-and-avoid-crash)

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution, i've implemented it in my app. Here is my code
sv_port is my scrollView.
Download SDWebImageDownloader class files and import it in your project. Add relevant framework in your project. like imageIO.framework, QuartzCore

Now, in your .m add

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "SDWebImageCompat.h"

//function for adding image in your scrollview
-(void)populateImages
{
int x=6,y=6;

for(UIView * view in sv_port.subviews){
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview]; view = nil;
    }
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview]; view = nil;
    }
}

for(int p=0;p<[Manufacturer count];p++)
{
    UIButton *btnImageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,70,70);
    [btnImageButton setTag:p];
    [btnImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextview:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinny = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinny.frame=CGRectMake(btnImageButton.frame.origin.x+25,btnImageButton.frame.origin.y+25, 20, 20);
    spinny.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [spinny startAnimating];

    [sv_port setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [sv_port addSubview:spinny];

    UIImageView *asyncImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:btnImageButton.frame] autorelease];
    asyncImageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    CALayer *layer;
    layer = asyncImageView.layer;
    layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    layer.masksToBounds = YES;


     [asyncImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourUrl] ]   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil] options:0 andResize:CGSizeMake(btnImageButton.frame.size.width,btnImageButton.frame.size.height) withContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    asyncImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [sv_port addSubview:btnImageButton];
    [sv_port addSubview:asyncImageView];
    int imgCntPort=0;

    imgCntPort=(sv_port.frame.size.width/(asyncImageView.frame.size.width));

    ////NSLog(@"imgport %d",imgCntPort);
    if((p+1)%imgCntPort==0)
    {
        x=5;
        y=y+80;
    }
    else
    {
        x=x+80;
    }
}
sv_port.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, y);
glob_x =0; glob_y =y;
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: Manufacturer is the array of your urls.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)scrollimage
{
    [AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader].cache = nil;
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [_scrollview_gallary subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGFloat width =_scrollview_gallary.bounds.size.width;

    _scrollview_gallary.contentSize=CGSizeMake(width*[tmpArr count]-1, 360);
    [_scrollview_gallary setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [_scrollview_gallary setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[tmpArr count]; i++)
    {
        AsyncImageView *imgv;
        imgv =[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,360)];
        imgv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        imgv.activityIndicatorStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
        NSString *strimag=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        imgv.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[tmpArr objectAtIndex:i]];
        [_scrollview_gallary addSubview:imgv];
        x=x+width;
    }
    _pageview.numberOfPages=([tmpArr count]);
    _scrollview_gallary.pagingEnabled = YES;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page;
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollview_gallary.frame.size.width;
    page = floor((_scrollview_gallary.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageview.currentPage = page;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting an impression that you are downloading all 300 images together at once and keeping in memory and adding to the UIScrollView..

There is a technique called LazyLoad, means don't load all the images at once, load it in queue..

You can refer to this link http://lazyloadinginuiscrollviewiniphone.blogspot.in/2011/12/iphone-uiscrollview-lazy-image-loading.html it might help you to achieve things smoothly..

All the best.

Comment: Yes, I am reading images and displaying them in UIScrollView dynamically, Increasing contentsize of uiscrollview, once it is out of memory it get crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display images in Gridview format then you can use [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView). And for the lazy loading of the image you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Answer (score 0):

Are you releasing the elements that are not visible anymore? UITableView does that (that's why Sandro suggested it).
Your implementation of the UIScrollView should do that.

You can also consider [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) or [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) for grid implementations that take this into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see why what you're doing is a problem. May be you've got memory issue. In that case simulator and device result should be different.

If this is a memory problem, you should use a tableview instead of a scroll view. Put 3 images in each table view cell, and that should do the trick.

Cdt